# How to run a file by another user in python Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am creating a python script which calls a shell script and run that shell script on a terminal using `Subprocess` . My problem is that I want to run that shell script by another user . My code is Given below

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
filename = '/mount/test.sh'
p = subprocess.Popen([filename],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

Can anyone tell me that how to run my shell script by another user ?

> Note:
>
> Only the subprocess part should be run by another user, not the main python script

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution

```
def change(user_uid, user_gid):
    def result():
        report_ids('starting demotion')
        os.setgid(user_gid)
        os.setuid(user_uid)
        report_ids('finished demotion')
    return result

def report_ids(msg):
    print 'uid, gid = %d, %d; %s' % (os.getuid(), os.getgid(), msg)


import subprocess
filename = '/mount/test.sh'
#mention UID and GID here
p = subprocess.Popen(filename, preexec_fn=change(1000, 1000))
result = p.wait()
print(result)
```

Note: I have used check_output instead of Popen. As I can't test it, please excuse if there is any typo or mistake. Also, check if p.communicate works with check_output.

Comment: I want to run shell script by another user which i am calling at subprocess but your solution runs main python script by another user too.

Comment: you can use a variable to provide user UID and GID and insert the variable at preexec_fn=change(VAR_UID, VAR_GID)

Comment: yes it is changing the user but there is some problem. suppose my python is running by sachin user and i want to run subprocess by root user , your solution is changing the user of subprocess but it is changing the user of python too. I want to change only subprocess user not main python .